# How to do clustering with langchain FAISS?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, faiss

I'm trying to do clustering on my Faiss vector

```
vector_store = FAISS.load_local("embeddings_of_songs", embeddings=embeddings)
```

but all I found on google is faiss similarity_search

I'm trying to do a kmeans clustering for `vector_store`, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to extract the embeddings from the vector store:

```
vectorstore_data = vector_store.get(include=["embeddings", "metadatas"])
embs = vectorstore_data["embeddings"]
```

Then applying clustering using sklearn:

```
# use a predefined number of clusters
num_clusters = 5

# Perform k-means clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0)
cluster_assignments = kmeans.fit_predict(embs)
```

---

Note that if there is some label (e.g. in the source of the metadata). You can inspect the quality of the clusters using ARI (see documentation). Here I assume the

```
categories = ...

# Evaluate clustering using adjusted Rand index (ARI)
ari = adjusted_rand_score(categories, cluster_assignments)

print(f"Cluster Assignments: {cluster_assignments}")
print(f"Adjusted Rand Index (ARI): {ari}")
```